# Setup proguard in toplevel build file for all modules in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, proguard

My project currently contains three modules, which all should be obfuscated on build.

Now I don´t want to define one proguard configuration each module, but one configuration for all modules.

There is the build.gradle toplevel build script, which is valid for all modules

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

**How can I configure proguard in this file, to be executed for all my modules?**

Answer (score 0):

You could store the proguard file on the projects extension properties, and then access that from each module:

Projects build.gradle:

```
allprojects {

    project.ext {
        proguardFile = "myproguardfile.txt"
    }

    repositories {
    }
}
```

Module:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles project.ext.proguardFile
    }
}
```